# Does Java 1.8.0_31 has the javafx.scene.control.Alert class how can I import it to my project

Tags: javafx-2

I'm trying to import Alert class but doesnt work. Does Java 1.8.0_31 has the javafx.scene.control.Alert class can I import it to my project

Comment: Just use your favorite zip tool and list the content of all jar files you can find in your Java installation. Then you will see where and if this class exists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java 1.80_31 *doesn't* have Alert. If you go through the [JavaDoc of Alert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) and scroll down, at the end of class description you will find the **since** tag which says `JavaFX 8u40`. As JavaFX follows the `update version of Java`, it means it is available since `Java 1.8.0_40`.

You need to use Java version greater than or equal to `Java 8 update 40` to use Alert in your project.

Comment: After I add openjfx-dialogs-1.0.2 librery it worked how is it possible

Comment: Because [OpenJFX-Dialogs](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs) is a fork of the original JavaFX Dialog implementation.